# How to pass querystring or hdnfield value to handler..?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I'm using a handler for my page and I want to pass value of querystring or hidden field on the page to the handler. and my handler code (Process Request Method) in separate file which is upload.ashx  I'm using the `context.request.param["ReqId"]` on .ashx file  but it does not get value.  Can any one help me?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClsCommon.ScreenId = ClsCommon.ScreenType.DeliveryManager;
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["ReqId"] != null)
        {
            hdnReqId.Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ReqId"]).ToString();

        }
        else
        {
            ClsSessionManager.ReferToError();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        ClsSessionManager.ReferToError();
    }
}

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Expires = -1;

    int Result;
    int ReqId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Params["ReqId"]);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Something Like this `Request.Form["ReqId"].ToString()`

Comment: I've deleted a chunk of your code because I think it's not helping your question. If you disagree please just undo my edit.

Comment: Hi RJK, i have tries it also its not giving me any value

Comment: how you pass ReqId to `upload.ashx`? can you update the question with code?

Comment: hi  Damith, that my question how i can pass any query string or hidden value to my handler

Comment: did you try call a handler with query string? 
ie. `myhandler.ashx?ReqId=value`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
int ReqId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Params["ReqId"]);
```

to

```
int ReqId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["ReqId"]);
```

for querystring values and

```
int ReqId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Form["ReqId"]);
```

for hidden values

Comment: that should read the values out of form and or querystring. Are you sure your passing them in? Is the context correct. Not sure what else I can say to help?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the value from the querystring

int ReqId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["ReqId"]);

Comment: Isn't this exactly what I said?